# Method 'GetEnumerator' in type Proxy<IEnumerable> does not have implementation

Tags: automapper

When using AutoMapper I get the following error

> Method 'GetEnumerator' in type 'Proxy' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.

In my repository I have a private method

```
private IMapper GetMapper()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<MyClass, PersistenceModels.MyClass>();
        cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<PersistenceModels.MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass>>();
    });

    return new Mapper(config);
}
```

And then I use this as follows

```
var mapper = GetMapper();
var userInfo = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PersistenceModels.MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass>>(userInfoRaw);
```

The `MyClass` types are identical and have an `IEnumerable` property

```
public IEnumerable<string> ImageUris { get; set; }
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

**Edit**

I am not mapping types defined by interface, I am mapping collections of concrete types, hence the `IEnumerable` interface.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution was not to use `IEnumerable` when creating maps, only when using the map.

So, in the configuration I changed from

```
cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<PersistenceModels.MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass>>();
```

to

```
cfg.CreateMap<PersistenceModels.MyClass, MyClass>();
```

and everything worked.

Answer (score 9):

I hit the same problem. I guess AutoMapper wants to be told which implementation of IEnumerable to use for the target, so the following worked for me.

```
cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<PersistenceModels.MyClass>, List<MyClass>>();
                                                      ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is older, but might help if you came here from Google...

Given:

```
cfg.CreateMap<PersistenceModels.MyClass, MyClass>();
```

You need to IEnumerable your destination:

```
var perData = dbContext.SomeDbSet.Where(.....);
var mapData = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(perData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue happens when using IList. So switch from IEnumerable or IList to List in destination type. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is unneccessary :
 `mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PersistenceModels.MyClass>, IEnumerable<MyClass>>(userInfoRaw);`
you must use just type map (without collections):

```
mapper.Map<PersistenceModels.MyClass, MyClass>(userInfoRaw);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this too.

```
public static class MapperHelper
{

    public static U CreateMap<T, U>(T dataSource)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<T, U>();
        });
        IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return iMapper.Map<T, U>(dataSource);

    }

    public static List<U> CreateMap<T, U>(T[] dataSource)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<T, U>();

        });
        IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return iMapper.Map<T[], List<U>>(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
MapperHelper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>(source.ToArray());
```